# Convergence of intensity function of self-exciting point processes imply convergence of processes?

Tags: self-study, convergence, point-process

For every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $N_n$ be the point process on $[0,1]$ defined by the conditional intensity function $\lambda_n: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R_{\geq 0}}$, where
$$ \lambda_n(t) = \mu_n(t) + \int_0^t \kappa_n(t-u) dN_n(u)$$
Suppose $\mu_n$ converges uniformly to $\mu$ and $\kappa_n$ converges uniformly to $\kappa$. Is it true that $N_n$ converges (Weakly? Strongly?) to the process $N$ with conditional intensity function $ \lambda(t) = \mu(t) + \int_0^t \kappa(t-u) dN(u)$?
If so, can these conditions be relaxed? If not, are there conditions for this to hold?
References are greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: I don't know the answers to your questions, but I would definitely look in the two volume book by Daley and Vere-Jones for the answers if you have access to that.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Will look into that.